# Why GridSearchCV spends more than 50% time on {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Recently I am tuning up some of my machine learning pipeline. I decided to take advantage of my multicore processor. And I ran cross-validation with param `n_jobs=-1`. I also profiled it and what was suprise for me: the top function was:

```
{method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
```

I was not sure if it was my fault due to operations I do in `Pipeline`. So I decided to make small experiment:

```
pp = Pipeline([('svc', SVC())])
cv = GridSearchCV(pp, {'svc__C' : [1, 100, 200]}, jobs=-1, cv=2, refit=True)
%prun cv.fit(np.random.rand(1e4, 100), np.random.randint(0, 5, 1e4))
```

The output is :

```
2691 function calls (2655 primitive calls) in 74.005 seconds
Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   83   43.819    0.528   43.819    0.528 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
    1   30.112   30.112   30.112   30.112 {sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit}
```

I wonder what is the cause of such behavior. And if it is possible to speed it up a little bit.

Comment: Did the actual wallclock time go down?

Comment: Yes it did. From: `1 loops, best of 3: 2min 7s per loop` using one job to `1 loops, best of 3: 1min 20s per loop` using four.

Comment: Then probably the profiler is only telling you what the main process is doing, while its child processes are doing all the work.

Comment: Indeed, the processing is actually done the multiprocessing children. You would need a way to plug a profiler onto one of them instead. It don't think the `%prun` magic can be made to profile the child processes though.

Comment: @larsmans Your comment should be the answer.

Comment: @Answeror: posted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The profiler is only telling you what the main process is doing, while its child processes are doing all the work. Setting `verbose=2` on `GridSearchCV` may give better output than `%prun` in this case.

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. Try what you suggest on a practical sized data set and the verbosity level will not show you anything about where the time is spent. In my case, the verbosity level shows ~30 sec of computation, which is how long a single cross validation score took to compute, but shows nothing about the >4 minuets time gap between two cross val scores, where nothing is being printed regardless of verbosity level.